# How to define block of code inside if condition

Tags: c, macos, if-statement

I work with old C project and should make there several changes
It has lots of macros....
The function calls are defined there as

```
#define myFunc(arg) myBaseFunc(arg)
```

`bool myBaseFunc` is a function, actually there are several `myBaseFunc` 
(its a kind of polymorphism)
I need to add some check of arguments correctness to `myFunc`
Actually the project has :

```
#define checkArg(arg) {\
 // lot of code
}
```

I can`t change `checkArg` implementation
1) I thought to //

```
/*It is not correct if I do `if(myFunc(arg))`*/

#define myFunc(arg)\
checkArg(arg)\
myBaseFunc(arg)
```

2)I thought to

```
/*It is better...but compiler doesn`t like code block `{}` inside`if(myFunc(arg))`*/

#define myFunc(arg)(\
checkArg(arg),\
myBaseFunc(arg))
```

Is there a workaround for this case

Comment: Please elaborate "compiler doesn't like code block `{}` inside`if(myFunc(arg))`" show the code and the compiler messages for that. The {} should not be a problem, if you use the `\\` carefully at the end of each and every line, other than in the shown code... I.e. please make a [mcve] of the code cases you describe.

Comment: @Yunnosch- int a = 1, b=0;
    if ((a>1, b))//ok  if (({a>1}, b))doesn`t compile

Comment: Why do you think you must use macros?  There are inline functions, and there are plain functions — either is better than a function-like macro.

Comment: is type of argument that is passed to marcos fixed? If yes, I may have a way....

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be able to show exactly which code did not compile, how exactly it did not compile (error messages verbatim, full and as text please). Also, it would not be as easy as telling you that you cannot have comments inside macros, would it? Or to put it differently, I can get it to compile, if you start giving much more information and doing so in a helpfully readable, formatted way, which is available only if you edit the question - not in comments. Show everything you have, explain, give details. Please.

Comment: The fact that `if (({a>1}, b))` does not compile is unrealted to macros. Please explain what you expect to achieve with a `{epxression}` inside the logical expression for an `if`. Please expalin what you want to achieve with a side-effect-free expression in the first part of a `,` operator construct.

Comment: Try this to get it to compile `if (({a>1;}), b)`. Then read the warnigs the compiler shows. Mine says `warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|` What does that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

I think It is possible like this, but you need to know argument type:

```
int main_check_function(void* data) { // <= this type need to be type of functions.
    checkArg(data);
    return (myBaseFunc(data));
}

#define myFunc(arg) (main_check_function(arg))
```

Although as I told, it is limited to knowing type. I just added a function to project to check your code by running `checkArg()` and then running `myBaseFunc()`. This approach is simple, but it has that big drawback.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to check the arg before it is passed to the base function. That works however only if there's only a single argument.

```
#define myFunc(arg) myBaseFunc(checkArg(arg))
```

Your `checkArg` function(s) must be changed so that they return the same value they got as parameter, e.g.

```
int checkArg(int value) {
  ... test stuff
  return value;
}
```

Comment: I cant change it. it should be a macro